# Nested JSON access / assigning values to UITextField

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a small app that allows users to catalogue books by looking up the ISBN on OpenLibrary. The idea is that the ISBN search takes the returned JSON data and uses it to populate UITextFields that the user can then further edit before saving.

I'm having issue accessing the nested JSON data and putting it into a UITextField. Accusing the top level of the dictionary and putting it into the UITextFields works fine, but when I try to go deeper, I get the error:

> Cannot assign a value of type String? to value of type 'String!'.

The JSON data it's taking is here: https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=0586057242&f&jscmd=data&format=json

Below is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ItemViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var authorField: UITextField!

    var session: NSURLSession!
    var items = NSObject()

    var lookUpID = "0586057242" // This will eventually get passed in from elsewhere.


    required init (coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)

        fetchItem()
    }

    func fetchItem() {
        let requestString = ("https://openlibrary.org/api/books?bibkeys=" + lookUpID + "&f&jscmd=data&format=json")
        if let url = NSURL(string: requestString) {
            let req = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

            let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(req) {
                (data, response, error) in
                if data != nil {
                    var error: NSError?
                    if let jsonObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as? NSDictionary  {

                        if let itemDictionary: AnyObject  = jsonObject["\(self.lookUpID)"]{
                            if let id = itemDictionary as? NSObject {
                                self.items = id

                                println("\(self.items)")

                                // Works.
                                self.titleField.text = itemDictionary["title"] as? String

                                // Does not work.
                                self.authorField.text = itemDictionary["authors"]["name"] as? String


                            }

                        }
                    } else {
                        if let error = error {
                            println("Error parsing JSON: \(error)")
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    println("Error fetching Item: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
            dataTask.resume()
        }
    }

}
```

I don't at all understand why it doesn't work, am I doing something wrong with the way I'm accessing the values?

Comment: do you know the difference between ? and ! in swift.

Comment: @Andrew Why you are  trying to assign non optional values to a variable that was declared optional ? The errors only says what wrong in it.

Comment: Yes, but what I don't understand is why the first `self.titleField.text = itemDictionary["title"] as? String` works but `self.authorField.text = itemDictionary["authors"]["name"] as? String` does not.

Comment: It appears `authors` is an _array_ of authors. Thus you might iterate on it extracting all the author's names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
var names = [String]()
if let authors = itemDictionary["authors"] as? NSArray {
    for author in authors {
        if let author = author as? NSDictionary,
            let name = author["name"] as? String {
                names.append(name)
        }
    }
}
self.authorField.text = join(",", names)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This worked a treat, thank you! As a follow up, when I run the application if I click into the UITextFields too quickly, the app crashes with an exception `''NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'` If I wait a short time, then click it doesn't crash. Is there an easy way to prevent this crash happening?

Comment: At first glance you might consider adding a boolean var `loading`. Set it to `true` while loading, and then to `false`. Do not start other processes if `loading` is `true`. Consider this a general schema, not sure if it fits your other problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the JSON again. Author node is returning array not dictionary. So, firstly you will have to get the dictionary from array then you should try to get name node from that dictionary.

So, think you try this:

```
self.authorField.text = itemDictionary["authors"][0]["name"] as? String
```

instead of using below line

```
self.authorField.text = itemDictionary["authors"]["name"] as? String
```

Comment: That still gives me the same error as above. _Cannot assign a value of type 'String?' to a value of type 'String!'_ I just don't understand why :/

Answer (score 0):

you should cast `itemDictionary["authors"]` as an array of authors and get individual author name like this:

```
let authors = itemDictionary["authors"]
for author in authors {
   self.authorField.text = author as! String
}
```

or for the first record

```
self.authorField.text = itemDictionary["authors"][0]["name"] as! String
```